# Android приложение запускается только на эмуляторе от андроид студио

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, genymotion

купил продвинутый курс по созданию приложения QuizApp. Прошёл 4 урока и понял что приложение работает только на эмуляторе от Андроид студио на других эмуляторах и реальных устройствах не работает. Автор не отвечает уже 2 недели. Прошу помощи хотя бы у вас потому что хотел выпустить её уже давно но никак не получается. Вот код активити что выбивает.
 КОД ПО ВТОРОМУ ОТВЕТУ

```
public class Tests extends BaseActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private AccountHeader header = null;
    private Drawer drawer;

    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList;
    private CategoryAdapter adapter = null;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tests);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvContent);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        initLoader();
        loadData();

        final IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withIcon(R.drawable.vnmu);

        header = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
                .withOnAccountHeaderProfileImageListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderProfileImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileImageClick (View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                        ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeCustomUrlActivity(Tests.this, CustomUrlActivity.class,
                                getResources().getString(R.string.site), getResources().getString(R.string.site_url), false);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileImageLongClick (View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .addProfiles(profile)
                .build();

        drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withHasStableIds(true)
                .withAccountHeader(header)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("О приложении").withIcon(R.drawable.vnmu).withIdentifier(10).withSelectable(true),

                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Настройки").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings).withIdentifier(30).withSelectable(true),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Оцінити програму").withIcon(R.drawable.result_ico).withIdentifier(31).withSelectable(true),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Поділитись").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_share).withIdentifier(32).withSelectable(true),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Ліцензія").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_privacy_policy).withIdentifier(33).withSelectable(true),

                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Вихід").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_exit).withIdentifier(40).withSelectable(true)
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick (View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem !=null){
                            Intent intent = null;
                            if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 10){
                                ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeNewActivity(Tests.this, AboutDevActivity.class, false);
                            }else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 30){
                                //TODO ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeNewActivity();
                            }else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 31){
                                AppUtilities.rateThisApp(Tests.this);
                            }else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 32){
                                AppUtilities.shareApp(Tests.this);
                            }else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 33){
                                ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeCustomUrlActivity(Tests.this, CustomUrlActivity.class,
                                        getResources().getString(R.string.privacy), getResources().getString(R.string.privacy_url), false);
                            }else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 40){

                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true) //TODO Перший запуск приложениия
                .withShowDrawerUntilDraggedOpened(true)
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {
        if(drawer !=null && drawer.isDrawerOpen()){
            drawer.closeDrawer();
        }else{
            AppUtilities.tapPromtToExit(this);
        }
    }

    private void loadData(){
        showLoader();
        loadJson();
    }

    private  void  loadJson(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(AppConstants.CONTENT_FILE)));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        parseJson(sb.toString());
    }
    private void parseJson(String jsonData){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConstants.JSON_KEY_ITEMS);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String categoryId = object.getString(AppConstants.JSON_KEY_CATEGORY_ID);
                String categoryName = object.getString(AppConstants.JSON_KEY_CATEGORY_NAME);

                categoryList.add(new CategoryModel(categoryId,categoryName));
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hideLoader();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Посоветуйте пожалуйста что не будь Логи делать не умею.

СategoryAdapter

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {



    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList;
    private  ListItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public CategoryAdapter (Activity activity, ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList) {

        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ListItemClickListener itemClickListener){
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    //public ViewHolder onCreateView

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_category_recycler, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, viewType, itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  CategoryModel model = categoryList.get(position);

        String categoryName = model.getCategoryName();
        holder.tvCategoryTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(categoryName));
        holder.tvCategoryId.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_blue);
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_red);
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_yellow);
                break;
            case 3:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_green);
                break;
            case 4:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_purple);
                break;
            case 5:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_orange);
                break;
            case 6:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_blue);
                break;
            case 7:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_red);
                break;
            case 8:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_yellow);
                break;
            case 9:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_green);
                break;
            case 10:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_purple);
                break;
            case 11:
                holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_orange);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return (null != categoryList ? categoryList.size() : 0);
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private RelativeLayout lytContainer;
        private TextView tvCategoryTitle, tvCategoryId;
        private ListItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public ViewHolder (View itemView, int viewType, ListItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
            lytContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lytContainer);
            tvCategoryId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
            tvCategoryTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

            lytContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            if (itemClickListener !=null){
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), view);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82064/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-bulan-android-----).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Убираем из MainActivity поля activity и context

вместо activity используем повсеместно this, а там где студия подчеркивает красным - MainActivity.this

context вообще безполезное поле, он не нужен в MainActivity

2) в адаптер не передаем ни то, ни другое. Не храним это в адаптере, вообще, если есть желание хранить где то ссылку на активность или контекст, то лучше отрубать руки, прежде, чем это сделать)) Уибираем их из адаптера и конструктора адаптера тоже

3) Заменяем все строки типа

```
holder.lytContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.rectangle_yellow));
```

на

```
holder.lytContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_yellow)
```

**У меня запустилось**

PS хранение ссылок на context - первый шаг к утечкам памяти. Даже если Вы решите как есть оставить строки

```
holder.lytContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.rectangle_yellow));
```

То

а) не используйте для этого applicationContext, используйте активити, она тоже является контекстом, и ресурсы лучше доставать через неё

б) не храните его в поле класса

в) Его всегда можно взять из view

```
holder.lytContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(holder.lytContainer.getContext(), R.drawable.rectangle_yellow));
```

PPS

И ещё если не сработает, попробуйте сделать clean - build

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82065/discussion-on-answer-by-iamthevoid-android-----).